# Uppaal template parameters

Tags: function, uppaal

I am using UPPAAL 4.1.19 and I am following the train tutorial, given in [this](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~adavid/RTSS05/UPPAAL-tutorial.pdf). In *Train* template, I put the parameters `int[0,N] e, const int id` and in the system declaration I declare `Train1=Train(el, 1);` and the system returns me "Incompatible argument" error for `e1`. I don't understand why it is actually incompatible? I have declared `N` as a constant equal to 5 in the global declarations, as well as `el`, but still it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: what is the type of `el`? it must be an integer. Did you mix it with `e1`?
not enough information here. You can save the model into an xta file and paste it as minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `int[0,N] &e, const int id`, similarly as here (page 6): https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/small_tutorial.pdf.